# How to reference self inside a closure

Tags: rust

If I have a struct like

```
// In app.rs
pub struct App {
    pub foo: bar[],
    pub bar_index: i32,
    pub true_false: bool
}

impl App {
    pub fn access<F: Fn(&mut OtherStruct)> (&mut self, action: F) {
        if let OtherStruct(baz) = &mut self.foo[self.bar_index] {
            action(baz);
        }
    }
}

// In main.rs
// `app` is a mutable variable defined elsewhere
app.access(|baz| {
    if app.true_false {
        // do something
    });
```

Running this `app.access` results in the borrow checker throwing a fit. I think it's because I'm referencing `app` within the closure, but I'm not sure how to fix it. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: Please provide us an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) e.g. by using [the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/). The struct `OtherStruct` is missing in this context. Try to reduce your example to a minimum so the problem stands for itself. Also please include the error in your question so we don't have to execute the code to see what's wrong.

Comment: *throwing a fit* — this is useless hyperbole. What *specific error(s)* do you get? Searching for an error message is one of the best ways to find solutions to a problem, but that only works when people *include those errors*.

Comment: `pub foo: bar[]` — this is not valid Rust code. You cannot make up syntax and hope that the compiler will figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `self` into `action` as a parameter:

```
impl App {
    pub fn access<F: Fn(&App, &mut OtherStruct)>(&mut self, action: F) {
        if let OtherStruct(baz) = &mut self.foo[self.bar_index] {
            action(&self, baz);
        }
    }
}
```

```
app.access(|app, baz| {
    if app.true_false {
        unimplemented!()
    }
});
```